# How to add a wallpaper-gallery to an Android application

Tags: android, gallery, wallpaper

I have noticed that some Android applications adds a new Wallpaper-gallery to the "Wallpaper-chooser".

I am currently building a theme for Android and I would like to add some wallpapers with this feature.

How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, that I have to write the code myself.

Found the code in the Home-sample in the SDK